# How to get indices for multiple insances of matched string using regexpr?

Tags: r, regex

I want to get index of both times `ap` appears in the string `ASDAS ap ASDASD ap AS`. I tried

```
regexpr("ap", "ASDAS ap ASDASD ap AS")[1]
```

But it only gives me the index of first match. How do I get index of both times the match for `ap` has been found?

Comment: Use `gregexpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gregexpr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

> `gregexpr` returns a list of the same length as `text` each element of which is of the same form as the return value for `regexpr`, **except that the starting positions of every (disjoint) match are given**.

See the sample code below:

```
> gregexpr("ap", "ASDAS ap ASDASD ap AS")[1] 
[[1]]
[1]  7 17
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_locate` from `stringr`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_locate_all("ASDAS ap ASDASD ap AS", "ap")
 #[[1]]
 #     start end
 #[1,]     7   8
 #[2,]    17  18
```